# How to apply a scalar multiplication to a Quaternion

Tags: javascript, c++, direct3d, quaternions, scalar

So, I'm converting some c++ to javascript and I really need to know how D3DX defines their quaternion operators.

```
 //Here's the c++ version
 D3DXQUATERNION Qvel = 0.5f * otherQuat* D3DXQUATERNION(angVel.x, angVel.y, angVel.z, 0);


 //Here's the js quat multiplication
   function quat_mul(q1, q2) {            
   return 
    [q1.x * q2.w + q1.y * q2.z - q1.z * q2.y + q1.w * q2.x,
    -q1.x * q2.z + q1.y * q2.w + q1.z * q2.x + q1.w * q2.y,
     q1.x * q2.y - q1.y * q2.x + q1.z * q2.w + q1.w * q2.z,
    -q1.x * q2.x - q1.y * q2.y - q1.z * q2.z + q1.w * q2.w]
```

**Is the scalar operation quat * 0.5f just like this?**

```
     quat.x *= .5;
     quat.y *= .5;
     quat.z *= .5;
     quat.w *= .5;
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [this link](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-cvs/2007-November/037925.html), it's like you say (and also in the quaternion number system):

```
inline D3DXQUATERNION& D3DXQUATERNION::operator *= (FLOAT f)
{
    x *= f;
    y *= f;
    z *= f;
    w *= f;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I think this misses the point.  If you're dealing with a quaternion representing a rotation, then only a unit quaternion is valid.  Scaling like this won't result in a unit quaternion for any scale other than 1.0.  While this may be an actual operator in the header, it does not produce a scaled rotation.

Comment: @Jherico: I don't get your point: the question was clearly about a multiplication by a scalar, not the scaling of a rotation.

Comment: I guess my point is that he's almost certainly asking the wrong question and that the original C++ code may be incorrect, if what he's trying to do is apply a scaled angular velocity, or convert angular velocity into a rotation by multiplying by a time factor.

Comment: @Jherico: I don't know what the OPs problem is, nor do I know if we're having an XY problem here. But I don't see how my response misses the point of the question, which is about scalar multiplication. But I guess it's worth mentioning for future readers :)

Comment: @Jherico The question clearly says he's porting code and needs to implement the same function in Javascript, so this answer is exactly right, I don't see any need to question the OP's grasp of his own situation.

Comment: Future reader here.  Was hoping to find out how to scale a rotation.  I guess the * operator isn't going to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I can verify this from a published source: Vince 2011 - Quaternion for Computer Graphics, page 57-58.

In simpler form:

```
q = [s, v] where s \in R and v \in R^3
\lambda q = [\lambda s, \lambda v] where \lambda \in R
```

In more complex notation:

```
q = a + bi + cj + dk

q * s = s * a + bi * s + cj * s + dk * s
      = s * a + (b * s)i + (c * s)j + (d * s)k
```

in javascript

```js
let quat = [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1];

function quaternion_scalar_multiplication(quat, s){
    quat[0] *= s;
    quat[1] *= s;
    quat[2] *= s;
    quat[3] *= s;
    return quat;
}
```